# Hadoop retry failed jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, jobs

I'm a hadoop noob, and I am taking over running some data from a colleague who is unavailable at the moment, so please, if you can, include obvious information in your answers.

I am running map reduce tasks, and the tasks will often fail because one or more jobs failed.  Upon retrying the tasks multiple times, they will eventually succeed if by luck no jobs failed.  The error log is very long, so if more of the error log is required, just shout.

there is a lot of repetition in the error log, and a lot of info logs, which I left out mostly.  snape, minerva, hagrid, dumbledore are names of local servers.

Is there a way for me to tell hadoop to just retry the failed jobs, instead of spending lots of time on the task, just to eventually delete the output because it had an error?
At the moment I have to retry the tasks multiple times (I have already run some tasks 10 times, and they still did not grace me with success).  This seems silly.  Any ideas?

```
...
...
014-11-27 12:30:04,453 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1417008757700_3632,job_1417008757700_3633,job_1417008757700_3636,job_1417008757700_3637,job_1417008757700_3638]
2014-11-27 12:30:17,373 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 77% complete
2014-11-27 12:30:17,373 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1417008757700_3633,job_1417008757700_3636,job_1417008757700_3637,job_1417008757700_3638]
2014-11-27 12:30:21,390 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 82% complete
2014-11-27 12:30:21,390 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1417008757700_3633,job_1417008757700_3636,job_1417008757700_3637,job_1417008757700_3638]
2014-11-27 12:30:34,486 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 87% complete
2014-11-27 12:30:34,487 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1417008757700_3633,job_1417008757700_3637,job_1417008757700_3638]
2014-11-27 12:30:57,726 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_1417008757700_3626 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-11-27 12:30:57,726 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_1417008757700_3633 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-11-27 12:30:57,726 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2014-11-27 12:30:58,728 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: snape/192.168.0.23:55798. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:30:59,729 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: snape/192.168.0.23:55798. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:00,730 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: snape/192.168.0.23:55798. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:00,834 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=FAILED. Redirecting to job history server
2014-11-27 12:31:00,874 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR 0: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException): No lease on /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1417008757700_3626_r_000000_3/part-r-00000 (inode 202543): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_attempt_1417008757700_3626_r_000000_3_838272402_1 does not have any open files.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkLease(FSNamesystem.java:3083)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.completeFile(FSNamesystem.java:3140)
...
...
...
...
2014-11-27 12:31:04,150 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 2 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-11-27 12:31:04,154 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.5.1   0.13.0  hduser  2014-11-27 12:27:08 2014-11-27 12:31:04 HASH_JOIN

Some jobs have failed! Stop running all dependent jobs

Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime  MinMapTIme  AvgMapTime  MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime    Alias   Feature Outputs
job_1417008757700_3627  2   1   11  4   8   8   12  12  12  12  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3628  2   1   10  4   7   7   26  26  26  26  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3629  2   1   11  5   8   8   38  38  38  38  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3630  2   1   9   4   7   7   40  40  40  40  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3631  2   1   9   3   6   6   10  10  10  10  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3632  2   1   10  3   7   7   49  49  49  49  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3634  2   1   10  4   7   7   10  10  10  10  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3635  2   1   10  4   7   7   10  10  10  10  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3636  2   1   9   3   6   6   14  14  14  14  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3637  2   1   12  5   8   8   17  17  17  17  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3638  2   1   9   3   6   6   30  30  30  30  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1417008757700_3626  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   Message: Job failed!    /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,
job_1417008757700_3633  r_cleaned,r_joined,r_metrics,r_top_cats HASH_JOIN   Message: Job failed!    /ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Failed to read data from "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Failed to read data from "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Failed to read data from "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 150124 records from: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/r_gp_prescription_metrics_final.csv"
Successfully read 10 records from: "/ccg_map_3/_GLOBAL/england_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Failed to produce result in "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"
Successfully stored 76033 records (67971674 bytes) in: "/ccg_map_3/2012_08/gp_r_tops_by_total_c.csv"

Counters:
Total records written : 836363
Total bytes written : 747688414
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1417008757700_3626
job_1417008757700_3627
job_1417008757700_3628
job_1417008757700_3629
job_1417008757700_3630
job_1417008757700_3631
job_1417008757700_3632
job_1417008757700_3633
job_1417008757700_3634
job_1417008757700_3635
job_1417008757700_3636
job_1417008757700_3637
job_1417008757700_3638


2014-11-27 12:31:05,155 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: hagrid/192.168.0.24:47581. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:06,155 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: hagrid/192.168.0.24:47581. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:07,156 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: hagrid/192.168.0.24:47581. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:07,258 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2014-11-27 12:31:08,288 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: minerva/192.168.0.22:44668. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:09,288 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: minerva/192.168.0.22:44668. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:10,289 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: minerva/192.168.0.22:44668. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:10,390 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2014-11-27 12:31:11,423 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: dumbledore/192.168.0.21:55195. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:12,424 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: dumbledore/192.168.0.21:55195. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:13,425 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: dumbledore/192.168.0.21:55195. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2014-11-27 12:31:13,527 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
...
...
...
```

Comment: I'm interested in helping you. What is 'task' and what is 'job' in your case? Is a task a shell script that launches map reduce jobs? What system are you using to create the job DAG? It seems unlikely to me that you have a system that can make a DAG of jobs but can't retry them or fail fast.

Comment: Hi @grasshopper.  A task is exactly as you say.  The jobs are created by hadoop; I just took the name from the error logs. We used to use Luigi, but my colleague has pretty much written something from scratch, but it is still pretty similar to Luigi.  I don't really know, so I did not mention it in the question, but I think that it may not retry the jobs because it cannot connect to the servers (it says that it is retrying to connect to server x).  If that has something to do with it or not - I don't know.

Comment: I was going to suggest luigi, as a matter of fact. You need a workflow manager for complex things, otherwise as you say, you sit all day and hope there are no failures. Luigi can retry jobs up to a set number of times automatically, and when you try to rerun it manually, it runs only the things that are not complete/failed. Idk why this is not happening in your case and it runs *everything* again. Either something is wrong with your coworkers custom solution or you're using it in a wrong way or network problems prevent you from seeing that certain jobs have run and their outputs exist in fact.

Comment: Another colleague of mine seems to have solved the problem, but does not know how.  Some things that he did:  restart all servers, update and recompile pig, fiddle with permissions, fiddle with hadoop.  Its not very exact, but its all I have.